Money management amidst family members and outside
I am looking for some examples (I did not find any on Quora or on this site).
What are some examples of families that shared their funds across their relatives as well as outside of their relatives realm?
Thanks.

Can you clarify your question? Are you looking for real life examples of parents giving their kids pocket money, which qualifies as sharing funds?

One possible example would be the case of Indian joint families where siblings and their respective families live under the same roof. Since they commonly live and eat together, they often pool their resources for their food and general upkeep of the house. Also, in case of emergencies, they share their wealth with each other. But at the same time, they also have their private funds which is exclusively for their family(wives and kids).
Couldn't think of any other examples.
